# Can we write javascript to run in the webmail? If so how do we handle such situation

Tags: javascript, email

Could any one of you explain me for the below situation. When I open a new mail the content of the mail(mini application with four or five modules) should be displayed in javascipt? How do u do that?

Comment: Please elaborate in more detail on your situation. What are you doing? What exactly do you mean by "displayed in Javascript"? Otherwise this question is very likely to be closed.

Comment: -1 because of putting an email link here and thinking it's acceptable to ask for private assistance on a public community. I've edited it out.

Answer (score 8):

Put it on a website and send people the link. I don't know of any mail application which is silly enough to allow javascript to run.